# Prolog - compare two numbers

Tags: prolog

I have some atoms that stand for the numbers 1 to 4 for example.

Like

```
number(one).
number(two).
number(three).
number(four).
```

Now I have to write a predicate that checks if the first number is bigger then the second one.

```
istBiggerThen(X,Y) :-
    (  X < Y
       -> true
       ;  false
    ).
```

But now I can only ask sth like

```
isBiggerThan(3,4).
```

But I want to

```
isBiggerThan(three,four).
```

How can I do that? Please help me :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to add facts that "map" English atoms to numeric values, and then use these facts to do comparisons, additions, and so on:

```
numericValue(one, 1).
numericValue(two, 2).
numericValue(three, 3).
numericValue(four, 4).
```

Now you can do this:

```
istBiggerThen(XinEng,YinEng) :-
    numericValue(XinEng, X),
    numericValue(YinEng, Y),
    /* The rest of your code goes here */
    (  X < Y -> true ;  false).
```

Note that `numericValue/2` can be used both ways - to convert names to numbers, and to convert numbers to names. For example, you can write a predicate that computes / checks the sum of two atoms spelled out using English names of the corresponding numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done without mapping atoms to numeric values:

```
num(one).
num(two).
num(three).
num(four).

isBiggerThan(X, Y) :-
    findall(Value, num(Value), Numbers),
    nth1(IndexX, Numbers, X),
    nth1(IndexY, Numbers, Y),
    IndexX > IndexY.
```

Sample input and output:

```
?- isBiggerThan(three,two).
true .

?- isBiggerThan(one,four).
false.
```

Comment: Very cute! My only problem with this approach is that it relies on the order in which the `num/1` clauses list the atoms. If someone who maintains this code decides to re-order them, say, alphabetically, `isBiggerThan` would work incorrectly.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, there are always pros and cons of various solutions. Yes, this approach is vulnereable to reordering of predicates but it is immune to wrong manual numbering and if you work with many sets or ordered data then you don't have to number everything. Also imagine a situation where you have to insert new predicate in the middle of already mapped set of facts and update **ALL** mappings of higher value. Or when you have to remove a fact. Do you see what happens then?

Answer (score 0):

```
greater(X,Y,Greater):-
        X > Y, Greater is X.
    
greater(X,Y,Greater):-
        X =< Y, Greater is Y.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled on this question almost eight years later but I think it's interesting. I saw a pattern for this while learning OCaml.

To define numbers atomically, each number is defined by being greater than the previous number. All numbers greater than the next number are also greater than the current number.

```
greater(one,zero).
greater(two,one).
greater(three,two).
greater(four,three).

greater(X, zero):- greater(X, one).
greater(X, one):- greater(X, two).
greater(X, two):- greater(X, three).
greater(X, three):- greater(X, four).
```

```
?- greater(four,one).
true.

?- greater(two,four).
false.

?- greater(zero,two).
false.

?- greater(three,zero).
true.
```

In english:

```
one is greater than zero
two is greater than one
three is greater than two
four is greater than three

greater than one means greater than zero
greater than two means greater than one
greater than three means greater than two
greater than four means greater than three
```